# sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts - can root see the password in clear text?

Tags: sudo, password, security

If some user can't access some command with `sudo` 3 times, this should be reported to root user in access logs\errors..

Can root see these attempts (like passwords tried) in text in the logs?

Comment: Implicit assumption: root is not being evil. If root is already being evil when you try to log in, all bets are off.

Comment: It is trivial to configure something on most systems, but its not part of any default config I know of.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd https://xkcd.com/838/

Comment: Just incorrect attempts counts are reported to root. Root can't see the entry passwords at all.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, passwords are not logged by default. This would be a security problem, as logs may be read by other administrators, allowing impersonation of the user in case of a slightly mistyped password.

Answer (score 29):

Login attempts successful and unsuccessful are logged in

```
/var/log/auth.log
```

Example of a successful attempt:

```
Oct 23 21:24:01 schijfwereld sudo: rinzwind : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rinzwind ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash
Oct 23 21:24:01 schijfwereld sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

And unsuccessful:

```
Oct 23 21:25:33 schijfwereld sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser=rinzwind rhost=  user=rinzwind
Oct 23 21:26:02 schijfwereld sudo: rinzwind : 3 incorrect password attempts ; TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/rinzwind ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash
```

It logs the failed attempt and logs also the total of 3 wrongly typed passwords.

Passwords for `sudo` attempts are never shown or stored.

Comment: The only way passwords are logged are usually when you forgot to hit enter after the username. So you log in as "Scott Tiger" instead of user Scott with password Tiger

Comment: But that's not sudo's fault ;-)

Comment: @Lenne when that happens to me (or otherwise when I absent mindedly type my password instead of a command), I delete the offending line from the shell history.

Answer (score 5):

The usual practice is to not log passwords used in login attempts, even if the password in question was invalid. This is simply because the password might be valid for another user on the same system (e.g. the user mistyped their *username*, not the password), or might be a trivial alternation of the actual password (the user missed a letter or so).

Either of those cases would leave a plaintext password laying on the system, vulnerable to some information leak. (The password might also be a valid password for some other system than the one it was entered on, but that's really more of a problem for "them", not "us".)

Somewhat related to this is the cases where a user writes their password in place of their username (e.g. they usually use a system that enters the username automatically, but now didn't, but still typed the password as the first thing). In that case, you would have a plaintext password in the logs. This is not optimal, but seeing the usernames for the usual failed login attempts is useful, and there's no simple solution for storing them but not passwords entered as usernames.

---

That said, there's nothing to stop the administrator of the system from having the system log the passwords, too. Adding the logging could probably be done by adding one call to `syslog()` and recompiling the PAM module. (PAM being what Ubuntu and `sudo` use, but of course the same applies for web apps and everything else, too.)

---

So, no, usually an administrator can't see the passwords entered on the system, **but** if you enter your password on a system you don't trust, you should, strictly speaking, consider it lost and change it.

Answer (score 0):

More generally speaking, *very* few programs in unix ever log actual passwords into syslog or elsewhere -- there's almost never a good reason to do so, and there are  good standing reasons *not* to.

Because of the way passwords are hashed, the system can't tell the difference between a wrong password and a typo - If your password was %$zDF+02G and you typed %$ZDF+02G it'll fail you as hard as it would if you typed 'rubberbabybuggybumpers', but logging the failed password would give *valuable* information away to a malicious third party reading the log.

The one case I've found where a program *did* have the capability to log passwords (and a use case where that'd be a good idea) is in RADIUS servers, where you can in a pinch switch on more-information-than-you-probably-wanted debug mode and then explicitly add the flag that means 'yes, *including* passwords' because you've got a client failing to connect and you need to rule out absolutely every possible cause...